# Iterate through 2 dates using bash script on mac

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I am trying to create a loop to iterate through 2 dates.
I have this so far, however it is going back in time. I want it to start with the start_date and end with the end_date.
I've tried to swap them around but it doesn't like that and adds +1day infinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
end_date="21-12-21"
start_date="21-11-20"
# Set a counter variable
counter=0

#Increase the counter to get back in time
while [ "$end_date" != "$start_date" ]; do
  end_date=$(date -v -${counter}d '+%y-%m-%d')
  echo $end_date
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

This is what it produces

```
21-12-23
21-12-22
21-12-21
21-12-20
21-12-19
21-12-18
21-12-17
21-12-16
21-12-15
21-12-14
21-12-13
21-12-12
21-12-11
21-12-10
21-12-09
21-12-08
21-12-07
21-12-06
21-12-05
21-12-04
21-12-03
21-12-02
21-12-01
21-11-30
21-11-29
21-11-28
21-11-27
21-11-26
21-11-25
21-11-24
21-11-23
21-11-22
21-11-21
21-11-20
```

I'm also running this on a mac which seems to be quite fussy with the date formatting. This is the only way I have found it to work so far.

Comment: As an aside, the first two bytes of the file need to be exactly `#` and `!` for the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to be valid.

Comment: oh thank you, Must have missed that when copying the code over

Comment: @newbiecoder - glad you got it working -- good luck with your scripting. (Linux will spoil you `:)`